# How to convert Fixed width Unix file to pipe delimited using column Ordinal Position and field length

Tags: text-processing

I want to convert a fixed width file to pipe delimited file in UNIX by using Column Ordinal Position and field length.

The input looks like this,

```
00100000003779U20210203
00200000004238U20210203
```

Required output:

```
001|0000000377|9U|20210203
002|0000000423|8U|20210203
```

Avaiable information is

```
Column Ordinal Position - field length 
1 - 3
2 - 10
3 - 2
4 - 8
```

Comment: Are you on UNIX or on Linux? You mention UNIX in your question but have tagged with [tag:Linux] instead. Please [edit] and clarify since the tools you will have available will depend on your operating system and Linux is _not_ the same as UNIX. Also, please show us what you have tried so far so we don't waste your time with solutions you have already attempted and which don't work for you.

Comment: Is the `Avaiable information` another input file or something you want to hard-code in your script or something else?

Answer (score 3):

This can help:

```
cut -b1-3,4-13,14-15,16-23 --output-delim="|" file
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk

```bsh
gawk -v OFS='|' -v FIELDWIDTHS="3 10 2 8" '{$1=$1; print}' file
```

```
001|0000000377|9U|20210203
002|0000000423|8U|20210203
```

The `$1=$1` trick forces awk to rewrite the record using the output field separator.

---

If you need something more portable, perl is ubiquitous:

```bsh
perl -lne 'print join "|", (/^(.{3})(.{10})(.{2})(.{8})/)' file
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I am able to get the output using field length. Thank you so much.